# Ansible run a task as a user with user's environment variables

Tags: bash, ansible, environment-variables, redhat, ansible-tower

I need to run a playbook from another user, but with that user's environment variables.
I suspected that simple `become` and `become_user` so I decided to check just that.
I tried to add flags to imitate `sudo su -l myuser` - it did not help.

Playbooks are launched by Ansible Tower, project scm is git (organisation local bitbucket).

```
---
- name: env checker
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Testing output
      debug:
        msg: "'{{ lookup('env', 'JAVA_HOME') }}' is the JAVA_HOME environment variable."
      become: yes
      become_user: myuser
      become_flags: "-l"
```

Is there a way to do this properly? Essentially I will need to run a bunch of shell commands that rely on a bunch of env variables, which is why I am checking this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've achieved such behavior by placing a script `env.sh` with content `JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest"` in directory `/etc/profile.d/`. By login it will be executed and provide the information which you try to gather.

Comment: I already have all of the vars in ~/.bash_profile at the moment
and sadly I don't have access to the server itself, only through Ansbile Tower

Comment: If it is on user level set correctly, can you include in your debug message `"{{ ansible_env }}"` and check what is listed there?

Comment: it says that "this task includes an option with an undefined variable"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to execute the playbook which reside in Ansible Tower and along with that command you can pass the relevant environment variables.

```
curl -f -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -POST --user username:password https://<ip-address-of-ansible-server>/api/v2/job_templates/<number-of-the-job-template>/launch/ --insecure  -d '{"extra_vars": "{\"variable1\": \"value-of-variable1\"}"}'
```

[image: Add your Variables here]

Comment: And we could do that probably by using Ansible module `uri` and specifying similar parameters.

Comment: I don't have access to the server directly, only from Ansible Tower, sadly

Comment: Then simply add the Environment Variables in Ansible Tower Templates. Navigate to the template section in Tower and there's an option called "Edit Survey". You can add the Variables there. I have uploaded a screenshot of it as well.